# Efficient way in MongoDB to find where docments properties match a subset of anothers

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm in need of an efficient way to find all the documents in a collection where their properties are a subset of a passed in object's properties.

Example:

```
PassedObject: { 
    name: "Joe",
    age: 55,
    sex: "male"
}

collection: [
    one: {
        age: 55
    },
    two: {
        sex: "male",
        age: 18
    },
    three: {
        sex: "male",
        age: 55
    },
    four: {
        sex: "female",
        age: 22
    },
    five: {
        make: "LG",
        model: "24EN43"
    }
]
```

The matched records would be one and three. I came up with a way to do this using `$ors` inside of `$ands`, checking if the property either didn't exist or was equal to the value but this was slow, and also produced false positives(for instance, document five(make: LG) would be returned).

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do the trick

```
db.searchTest.find({$and:[{$or:[{name:{$exists:false}},{name:"Joe"}]},{$or:[{age:{$exists:false}},{age:55}]},{$or:[{sex:{$exists:false}},{sex:"male"}]},{$or:[{name:{$exists:true}},{age:{$exists:true}},{sex:{$exists:true}}]}]})
```

To make this efficient, you need to build appropriate indexes on your data